# How to check if there's a performSelector: waiting to be executed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, performselector

In my iPhone app I got several places where I can do a

`[object performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]`

call. All lead to the same method. Now, in that method I want to execute some code only on the latest call of it. If it was the first, I could just do `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thisMethod) object:nil]` and be sure it gets called once.

But, is there a way to tell if there are any other method calls waiting to be executed?

I could use a counter in this class that I would increment each time I set this perform after delay, then decrement it at start of each call and only execute the code if this counter is zeroed. But I'm wondering if it's the best/acceptable approach...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well what you could do is this: anytime you call `[object performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` just add the line you mentioned above it. You could actually create a method that handles that for you. For example:

```
- (void)performSelectorOnce:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)object afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:object selector:selector object:object];
    [self performSelector:selector withObject:object afterDelay:delay];
}
```

and than where ever you use `[object performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` just replace it with [self performSelectorOnce: withObject: afterDelay:];

If you want to use this in multiple objects than you could actually create an NSObject category and add the method there.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: What if you just want to ignore successive calls without modifying the first scheduled one? For instance calls to update a table view.