# is there way to check if performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: has been registered?

Tags: objective-c, selector

I whould like to know if there is a way to determine if  `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` for the given object has been called (registered to be called). (I could use `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` and re-call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, ok but I'm interested to know if there is the alternative).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if there's a performSelector: waiting to be executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659584/how-to-check-if-theres-a-performselector-waiting-to-be-executed)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do would be to make sure that the selector being called can be called multiple times safely.

For example, use a flag in the target object to track if the method has already been invoked e.g.

```
-targetSelector: (id) param
{
    if (!hasBeenRun) // hasBeenRun is a boolean intance variable
    {
        hasBeenRun = true;
        // other stuff
    }
}
```